# Java Web Application Development Tools - Versions

Tags: java, web-applications

I'm in the process of learning about servlet containers and web apps based on Java EE, servlets, JSPs, EL/JSTL, JDBC (via Connector J from MySQL AB), MySQL server, etc.

I usually like to know in detail about the versions of the tools I'm using (and also thinking ahead of when I might list these on a resume).

From the command line (I'm running Cygwin on Windows XP) I can easily find the versions of java, ant, and mysql. Other components, however, come with these or are downloaded and installed as .jar files, so I'm not quite as clear about how to verify the versions I have installed.

How would I find the specific versions of the following:

```
1. Connector J (JDBC)
2. Java Servlet API
3. JavaServer Pages API
4. JSTL API
```

Comment: Many jars will have the version number in their file name I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking online, I was able to find the versions for JSP and Servlet, though I'm still going off the documentation and not necessarily what's installed:

"Tomcat 7.0 implements Java Servlet 3.0 and JSP 2.2"